# error menu drodown css html <nav> <ul>

Tags: html, css, nav

I am creating a page where there is a menu that contains a submenu centered at the top of the page, my problem is being to centralize the submenu with the main menu, because it always goes out of alignment, does anyone know what it can be? Thank you in advance for any help!
"ps:in the image contains the visible error"

edit1:run and with the link and with the html that was missing.
link:https://testtestteste111111.000webhostapp.com/

```
 .menu{
 width:100%;
 height:49px;
 background-color:#494545;
 font-family:'Arial';
 position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index:9999;
  }
 .menu ul{
 list-style:none;
position:relative;
margin-left:24%;
}
.menu ul li{
 width:150px;
  float:left;
  }
 .menu a{
 padding:15px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#494545;
 color:#fff;
  }
 .menu ul ul{
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
 }
.menu ul li:hover > ul{
  visibility:visible;
 /* border:1px solid #901E93; sub div*/
  }
  .menu a:hover{
  background-color:#7F818D;
color:#fff;
 }
  .menu ul ul li{
     float:none;
     border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
     margin-left:-164%;
     }
     .menu ul ul li a{
         background-color:#646464;
         }
         label[for ="bt_menu"]{
             padding:5px;
             background-color:#494545;
             color:#fff;
             font-family:"Arial";
             text-aling:center;
             font-size:30px;
             cursor:pointer;
             width:100%;
             max-height:58px;
             z-index:9999;

margin-top:-10px;
top:-5px;
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
         }
         .imgbar{
             max-height:25px;
             max-width:25px;
             margin-top:10px;
         }
         #bt_menu{
             display:none;
           }
   @media(max-width:800px){
   label[for="bt_menu"]{
   display:block;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:9999;
   position:fixed;
   margin-top:1px;
   }
   .menu{
    margin-top:-1px;
    margin-left:-100%;
    transition:all .4s}
    #bt_menu:checked ~ .menu{
        margin-left:0;}
    .menu ul li{
    width:100%;
    float:none;}
    .menu ul ul{
        position:static;
        overflow:hidden;
        max-height:0;
        transition:all .4s;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover ul{
        height:auto;
        max-height:200px;
    }
  .menu ul{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
margin-left:0;
z-index:9999;
}
.menu ul ul li{
     float:none;
     border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
     margin-left:0;
     }
     .parallax { 
        width:100%;
/* The image used */
background-image: url(../img/img1.jpg);

/* Set a specific height */
height: 800px; 

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
margin-top:-50px;
  }
#ultopo{
margin-top:49px;
}}
html
<input type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">
<label for="bt_menu"><img class="imgbar" src="img/bars.svg"></img></label>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul id="ultopo">
   <li><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>

  <!-- nested UL in LI -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ex:A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ex:b</a></li>
   </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Atuaçao</a>
  <!-- nested UL in LI -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ex:A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ex:B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ex:C</a></li>
  </ul>   
    </li>    
    <li><a href="#">contato</a></li>
   </ul>
   </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: much better if you could show us a working copy of it like in jsfiddle

Comment: Or at least provide you html as well

Comment: https://testtestteste111111.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: example - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vrhnjzcd/. 1) .menu ul li - position: relative; 2) .menu ul ul - margin-left: 0; 3) .menu ul ul li - remove margin-left:-164%;

Comment: Many thanks, it worked perfectly !!! : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update css

Here is link https://jsfiddle.net/jbv09vy4/1/

Add css

```
.menu ul li {
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and remove styles `margin-left: -164%` from

```
.menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin-left: -164%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is very helpful !!

Comment: Happy coding mate